# What does this invocation of a char array cast as a function do?

Tags: c, function-pointers, shellcode

I came across this piece of code:

```
char code[] = "\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80";
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int (*func)();
    func = (int (*)()) code;
    (int)(*func)();
}
```

It is copied from [Writing Shellcode for Linux and Windows Tutorial](http://althing.cs.dartmouth.edu/local/shellcode.html).

Could someone explain that what this function invocation `(int)(*func)();` is doing?

Comment: @Downvoter; A comment would be appreciated.

Comment: It calls a function whose machine code is in the array `code`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès; Could you explain it.

Comment: @Matt McNabb; I don't think that question asking for same.

Comment: The other question explains what `(int)(*func)();` is doing in the question body (he asks what it's doing and then correctly answers his own question). It's the exact same code

Comment: @MattMcNabb; I was more interested in how it is executing that .

Comment: do you mean you're asking what the assembly instructions represented by `\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80` are? In either case I'd suggest commenting on the other question's Answer asking for further explanation if needed

Comment: Possible reason for downvote: the title was too generic. Tried to improve that in my edit.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视; Thanks. Agreed with your comment and profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It calls a function whose machine code is in the array `code`. The *string* contains some machine-level instructions ((three I think, have a look at x86 instruction set). `func` is declared as a pointer to a function that takes no argument and returns an `int`. `func` is then set to the address of the first byte of that *string* (machine instructions remember). Then `func` is called, so a function call to the first instruction of the *string* is made.

I don't now x86 instruction set very well, but it seems to make a system call (don't know which one); `0xcd 0x80` is a trap to the system.

---

As @etheranger said, it is a call to the `_exit` system call.

Beware that this is Linux-dependent, see [What does "int 0x80" mean in assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817577/what-does-int-0x80-mean-in-assembly-code)

A short explanation for this mechanism is available here: http://www.linfo.org/system_call_number.html

Comment: The source linked in the question implies that it's an `exit` call.